# Camel Configure Redelivery Police at Runtime

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I need to change on exception redeliver policy at runtime I added howtio to my project but it only allows me to change errorHandler Policy, not onEception

code sample

```
    onException (IOException.class)
            .maximumRedeliveries (3).maximumRedeliveryDelay (1000)
            .bean (IoExcpetionRouterBean.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the redelivery policy of OnException  by creating bean RedeliveryPolicyDefinition and change

onException (Throwable.class)
                .bean (*RoutingSlip.class , "slip").setRedeliveryPolicy (redeliveryPolicyDefinition);

whenever I change redeliveryPolicyDefinition object it affects at runtime

I consider this as a workaround solution as per @Claus Ibsen that this can be done by JMX  but I couldn't with JMX I could only change configuration error handlers not route  onException